Better wat to set dynamic type from DB value
It's probably dumb or bad design (I've found a work around), but I have one class who look like this:
public class Post<T>: BaseEntity where T : IPostContent
{
    ...
    public required string Type { get; set; }
    ... 
    public T Content {  get; set; }
}

IPostContent is an interface use in classes like Media or News where I have different properties related to the nature of the content.
In my DB, I have a table Post that looks like this and where Content is a JSON string:
CREATE TABLE Post (
    [Id]                    BIGINT              IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
    [Type]                  NVARCHAR(50)        NOT NULL, 
    [Content]               NVARCHAR(MAX)       NULL,
    ...
);

Is it possible to set the Content property when reading the DB with the Type column? And how to do it?
I'm doing this workaround instead (without IPostContent interface and all the classes) but it feels dirty and loosely type:
var post = new DataModel.Post.Post()
{
     ...
     Type = reader["Type"].ToString(),
     Content = reader["Content"] != DBNull.Value ? JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonNode>(reader["Content"].ToString()) : null,
     ...
};


How is your Post class, you show at the end of your question, connected to the generic Post at the start? Did not get completely where you are heading with this question. But if you only know the concrete T at runtime generics will be in your way and not help you. They are made for type safety at compiletime. When you only know things at runtime you may use generics in weird ways but you will most likely work against it. You may think about putting the type into the json. JsonSerializers can use that to correctly instanciate from that the needed correct type. ....

But at runtime the best you can use to program against that will be IPostContent you can't write code that knows its a Media or News as a generic type of a class.

@Ralf you confirm my thought about type safety at compile time, I'll stick with JsonNode... it works, but I was searching to improve my code.
